# Separating words and put it to array?

Tags: php

`User-agent: * Disallow: / kadirgamar/ Disallow: / arrow/ Disallow: / orion/ Disallow: / woolimlanka/ Disallow: / nippon/ Disallow: / luna-tower/ Disallow: / thotalagala/ Disallow: / altair/ Disallow: / arrowlibrary/ Disallow: / ashraf/ Disallow: / ashrafnew/ Disallow: / invoke/ Disallow: / lavana/ Disallow: / leia/ Disallow: / lorelle/ Disallow: / lioc/ Disallow: / liocdev/ Disallow: / lorellenew/ Disallow: / openmanthri/ Disallow: / opentapes/ Disallow: / rates/ Disallow: / rsq/ Disallow: / signature/ Disallow: / site/ Disallow: / visualretale/ Disallow: / srhr/ Disallow: / smitratest/ Disallow: / smitra/ Disallow: / lioccontent/ Disallow: / lioccopy/ Disallow: / liocold/ Disallow: / global/ Disallow: / echelon/ Disallow: / arrowlive/`

this is my string. I have to separate kadirgamar, arrow etc these words. How can I separate and put it to array in php?

I tried this:-

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://www.test.oddly.co/robots.txt';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result.'<br>';
$arr = array("lorelle","kadirgamar","arrow","orion","woolimlanka","nippon","luna-tower","thotalagala","arrowlibrary",
    "ashrafnew","invoke","lavana","leia","lorelle","lioc","liocdev","lorellenew","openmanthri","rsq","signature",
    "site","visualretale","srhr","smitratest","smitra","lioccontent","lioccopy","liocold","global","echelon","arrowlive"
);

$str = explode('Disallow: /',$result,-1);

?>
```

I have tried this but its giving error.
I want to check that two array is that equal or not? how can I do that?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: `explode` can help you.

Comment: $str = explode('Disallow:/',$vstring,-1);
this one is giving erroe

Comment: If you have attempted to write some code, please show us the code

Comment: There is a space between `Disallow:` and `/` try `explode('Disallow: / ',$vstring);`

Comment: explode('Disallow: / ',$vstring); this one is giving / after every words. Only word should be there.

Comment: and User-agent: * this one is also storing. but this one should not be stored into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$array = explode('Disallow: / ',$vstring); //explode string to array

unset($array[0]); // to remove first word User-agent: * 
$array = array_values($array); // re-index array

function trim_array_element(&$item1)
{
    $item1 = preg_replace('/\//', '', $item1);
}

array_walk($array,'trim_array_element'); // apply custom function to remove / from each values of array

print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/914410

Comment: Thank you so much.